# Add image over another image?

Tags: java, image

Im trying to make a turn-based game, progressing OK so far, however now I came to the part where I want to be able to move units around. I use images to determine different types of terrain, and another image to display a unit, but I can't get the unit to come out OVER the terrain, it only pops up under the terrain. Seems like I'm the first one ever to bump into this problem, so am I going at it the wrong way?

The tile with a terrain-image:

```
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics paintIt) //paints this sexy-hex
{
    super.paintComponent(paintIt);  //not sure if we need this? lol
    paintIt.setColor(is);   //sets the color (later not even used, we need pics and shit)
    //paintIt.fillPolygon(hex); //fills the hexagon with the desired color, will not be used later on either
    if(isExplored)
        paintIt.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

    else
        paintIt.fillPolygon(hex); // I want to paint it black


    if (hoover) //are we pointing at this cell?
    {
        paintIt.setColor(Color.WHITE);  //we want the nice line around the cell to be white
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) paintIt;   
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));   //and 3 pixels wide (we are allowed to change it, supposedly in proportion to "rad"
        g2.drawPolygon(hex);    //draws the line around the hexagon
    }       
}
```

The unit:

```
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics paintIt)
{
    if(!selected)
    {
        paintIt.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        paintIt.drawImage(image2,0,0,null);
        /*
        super.paintComponent(paintIt);
        paintIt.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paintIt.drawPolygon(shape); */  
    }
    else
    {
        super.paintComponent(paintIt);
        paintIt.setColor(Color.RED);
        paintIt.drawPolygon(shape); 
    }
}
```

Sorry for the comments, and sorry for some code that's not even used, just think it's best to have it until the project's finished if we need to get back to somewhere.
The unit image is smaller than the terrain, so it fits. I've tested without painting out the terrain so I know the unit is painted under it. 
If there's still code you would need to get an idea what I'm doing, tell me, just thought this was the relevant parts.
**EDIT #2**
The tile is a class created from another class which extends JFrame. The unit-class is created from that JFrame class but is beeing stored in the tile. Both tile and unit are JComponents.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like your going about it the wrong way. If you provide source code to illustrate what you are doing, it is easier to point you in the right direction.

Comment: What Java GUI system are you using: Swing, Swt ... ???

Comment: Plenty of possible causes, growing linearly with the number of possible toolkits you could be using. Narrow it down for us! And post some delicious code!

Comment: I sure did not waste a lot of my time.  ;)

Comment: @user: Andrew might not have used the best tone, but his message is true: when using an existing library (especially a much-used one), it's usually **much** safer to assume that there is no bug in it but that your code is the problem (at least until proven otherwise).

Comment: I never claimed it to be a bug, just meant that I searched every single byte on the interwebz but there doesn't seem to be anyone that had the same issue. The closest I came to a solution was to add both images into a third image, but it doesn't feel right. Why shouldn't I be able to just add an image over another? I doubt there is any fault in my code, it's simply not made to achieve the effect I'm after, since I don't know how. Which is why i'm here.

Comment: It isn't as obvious as the terrain being drawn after the units, is it?

Comment: It's actually the other way around, since the terrain is only drawn once when the map is generated but the units can move around anytime during runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix'd, I had to draw the units image within the terrain-class to make it come out on top. Since I already stored the unit in the class I don't know why I didn't do it this way from the beginning.
Thanks anyhoo <3